# Confirming valid HTML tags in file using a stack C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, stack

I need to read an `HTML` file and confirm that all of the `HTML` tags are properly closed using a `Stack` to do so. I am have trouble right now reading the file and finding each tag. I am not sure how I should proceed. Should I read each line of the file, use regex to find the tags, then add to the stack... or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every hand-made solution you will attempt to use will become a nightmare. I really recommend you to use an external library that can handle `HTML` properly. With [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) this task becomes a joke:

```
// your string variable containing HTML
String html = ...

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (HtmlParseError error in document.ParseErrors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + error.Code.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(error.Reason);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: If I am correct, that for loop is just checking for errors? Am I wrong? Also this code is just loading the html document, is that correct?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. You load the document (or a string containing the HTML) and then you print the eventually found errors. There could also be none, and in that case no message will be shown.

Comment: Sadly I am forced to use a stack to confirm if there are any errors. This does look very convenient though. Is it possible to make this work with a stack?

Comment: I still have to understand what a stack is in this context.

Comment: A stack is a collection of objects that follows a "the first in last out" rule of thumb. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah ok, THAT stack. Well, just push the errors inside your stack within the foreach. Use a generic Stack<T> where T = HtmlParseError.